# C++ Qt Application window is small

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

My Qt designer implementation:
[image: Qt designer]

When my application compiles using Visual Studios:
[image: Compiled]

Why is compiled gui not appearing in the same size as the previewed in Qt designer?

My main.cpp:

```
#include "Send2Server.h"
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QApplication::setStyle("fusion");
    QDesktopWidget dw;
    Send2Server w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
```

As provided in the comments, here is some extra code:

Send2Server.h:

```
#include "Send2Server.h"

using namespace std;


Send2Server::Send2Server(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    //insert connect button commands
}
//Commands here
```

Send2Server.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_Send2Server.h"
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Send2Server : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Send2Server(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

private:
    Ui::Send2ServerClass ui;

private slots:
    //commands here
};
```

My Qt design style that might be causing the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Send2ServerClass</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="Send2ServerClass">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>434</width>
    <height>230</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Send2Server</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <property name="sizePolicy">
    <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
     <horstretch>10</horstretch>
     <verstretch>0</verstretch>
    </sizepolicy>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QWidget{

background-color:#282c34;
text-color: white;
}</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="server_input">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>110</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLineEdit{
background-color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="send_file">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>300</x>
      <y>200</y>
      <width>56</width>
      <height>17</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton{
background-color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Send File</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="server_address">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Microsoft YaHei UI</family>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLabel{
color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Server Address:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="user_input">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>110</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLineEdit{
background-color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLineEdit" name="pass_input">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>110</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>311</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLineEdit{
background-color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="file_location">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>171</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLabel{
color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="choose_file">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>220</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="sizePolicy">
     <sizepolicy hsizetype="Maximum" vsizetype="Maximum">
      <horstretch>0</horstretch>
      <verstretch>0</verstretch>
     </sizepolicy>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton{
background-color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Choose File</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="username">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>60</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Microsoft YaHei UI</family>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLabel{
color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Username:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="password">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>100</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Microsoft YaHei UI</family>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLabel{
color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Password:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="private_key">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>140</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Microsoft YaHei UI</family>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLabel{
color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Private Key:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="file">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>21</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <family>Microsoft YaHei UI</family>
      <pointsize>10</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLabel{
color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>File:</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="choose_key">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>220</x>
      <y>140</y>
      <width>101</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton{
background-color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Choose your Private Key</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QLabel" name="key_location">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>90</x>
      <y>140</y>
      <width>131</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QLabel{
color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="clear_file">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>340</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton{
background-color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Clear File</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="clear_key">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>340</x>
      <y>140</y>
      <width>81</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">QPushButton{
background-color: white;
}</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Clear Private Key</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources>
  <include location="Send2Server.qrc"/>
 </resources>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: I think it might have to do with the `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);` line, try removing that and see if it improves.

Comment: Just took it out, and the window remains the same.

Comment: How about: `QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_DisableHighDpiScaling);`, it looks like it has something to do with *High Display Monitor Scaling*... See the issues with DPI [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html#issues-with-high-dpi), which accurately matches up with yours...

Comment: I had the setAttribute in my code but I still had the same window size.

Comment: @AjayShah Have you tried *disabling* it instead of *enabling*?... Because the last time you *had* `setAttribute()` in your code, it was set to `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling`...

Comment: @Ruks just set it to disable and I still have the small window

Comment: @AjayShah It can happen that the problem *might* lie somewhere outside the `main.cpp` code... You will have to provide some more code other than the code for `main.cpp`

Comment: @Ruks included additional files in the post

Comment: some of this has to do with the style, but the difference in size could be something that the window manager is doing.  It has final say about placement and size, so depending on what you are using, it could be the cause.

Comment: @BobShaffer any suggestions on how to fix this

Comment: First, drop the style to see how much of it is caused by this.  Next, check your window size properties (SizePolicy, MinimumSize, MaximumSize) on the window and see if something there may be causing the resizing.  Maybe just setFixedSize() to prevent any resizing if that is appropriate.  If you do all of that and it's still getting resized, you really need to just figure out why.  It could be something to do with high DPI displays as already suggested, it could be a WM ignoring hints for some reason, or something else.

Comment: @BobShaffer added my qt ui file in the post

Comment: what is the geometry of the actual window when you run it?  (if x11, xwininfo in a terminal will tell you.  idk about other systems).  the image you posted is within 1px horizontal and about 40 off vertical (titlebar?).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187815/discussion-between-bob-shaffer-and-ajay-shah).